# configure user for docker on Linux

Tags: linux, centos, docker

I have installed docker on `Linux` `Centos7` environment.

I can run docker command as `sudo`:

```
[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ sudo docker run hello-world

**Hello from Docker!**
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

I wish to run it as non `root` user. so I followed the official documentation

First, I added the group `docker`

```
[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ sudo groupadd docker
```

When I tried to add user as `'xyz'` I am getting this. Am I doing something wrong?

```
[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ sudo usermod -aG docker $xyz
Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN

Options:
  -c, --comment COMMENT         new value of the GECOS field
  -d, --home HOME_DIR           new home directory for the user account
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -g, --gid GROUP               force use GROUP as new primary group
  -G, --groups GROUPS           new list of supplementary GROUPS
  -a, --append                  append the user to the supplemental GROUPS
                                mentioned by the -G option without removing
                                the user from other groups
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -l, --login NEW_LOGIN         new value of the login name
  -L, --lock                    lock the user account
  -m, --move-home               move contents of the home directory to the
                                new location (use only with -d)
  -o, --non-unique              allow using duplicate (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       use encrypted password for the new password
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -P, --prefix PREFIX_DIR       prefix directory where are located the /etc/* files
  -s, --shell SHELL             new login shell for the user account
  -u, --uid UID                 new UID for the user account
  -U, --unlock                  unlock the user account
  -v, --add-subuids FIRST-LAST  add range of subordinate uids
  -V, --del-subuids FIRST-LAST  remove range of subordinate uids
  -w, --add-subgids FIRST-LAST  add range of subordinate gids
  -W, --del-subgids FIRST-LAST  remove range of subordinate gids
  -Z, --selinux-user SEUSER     new SELinux user mapping for the user account
```

After this I ran:

```
[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ docker run hello-world
/usr/bin/docker-current: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.26/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See '/usr/bin/docker-current run --help'.
```

I did try adding user like:

```
[xyz@innolx20122 ~]$ sudo usermod -aG docker xyz
```

and then I tried

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

still getting same issues. I can't run docker commands without root user or sudo.

Comment: You need to relogin after doing the `usermod`

Comment: type exit in terminal and then login again?

Comment: Yes, it will apply the changes

Comment: It didn't worked.. still has to prefix sudo

Comment: Do: `su $(whoami)`

Comment: yepp.. Its working now.. only these commands need sudo access.. like systemctl status docker, systemctl enable docker, systemctl start docker